# How can I properly inject HazelcastMap into a class using Guice?

Tags: java, cdi, guice, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a standard CDI bean named NamedService;

```
@Named
public class NamedService {

@com.google.inject.Inject
private HazelcastService hazelcastService;

public void writeSomething() {
    if (hazelcastService != null) {
        System.out.println("injected properly.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("hazelcastService null");
    }
}
```

}

which injects HazelcastService;

```
@Named
public class HazelcastService {

    @Inject
    @HazelcastMap(name = CacheConstants.CONFIGURATION_MAP)
    protected IMap<String, String> configurationMap;

}
```

They are binded in the specified Module class:

```
public class NamedServiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(NamedService.class);
        bind(HazelcastService.class);
    }
}
```

When I try to see whether hazelcastMap injected properly, It throws an exception;

```
public class TestGuice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new NamedServiceModule());
        NamedService namedService = injector.getInstance(NamedService.class);
        namedService.writeSomething();
    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable
>   to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for com.hazelcast.core.IMap was bound.   while locating
>   com.hazelcast.core.IMap
>       for field at com.sqills.s3_ticket.service.util.HazelcastService.configurationMap(HazelcastService.java:11)
>   at
>   com.sqills.s3_ticket.service.util.NamedServiceModule.configure(NamedServiceModule.java:10)

When I remove the hazelcastMap injection then the injection is successful. How can I properly inject that hazelcast map by using Guice?

Comment: The exception message is straightforward. In `HazelcastService` class you are trying to inject `configurationMap` which is of type `IMap<String, String>` but this binding is not defined in your Guice module.